# Jquery mobile ui and Samsung Galaxy s4

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, mobile, browser-detection

I am using Jquery Mobile UI and am finding that Samsung Galaxy S4s are not detected as being mobile devices. Is there a way to force them to be seen as mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

Use this meta tag inside your `<head>` section, this will solve your problem =)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```